# What is the purpose of "Go To" in Developer Console

Tags: developer-console

I'm trying to understand what "Go To" button in the Developer Console does. I've gone through salesforce help docs but it wasn't mentioned anywhere. I've even gone through lot of developer console tutorial videos....no one really talked about it.

I've one more question regarding the test execution. Earlier the latest test execution used to show up on top (Sorted descending). After Summer '15 showed up, they are being sorted ascending which puts latest test run at the bottom. I had to change the sorting order every time....Any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to button is useful to retrieve Symbol table for class or Trigger. I checked in my org and opened a trigger and pressed "Go To" then you will get symbol table if associated or you will get an error massage if not associated.

[image]

Comment: Yes...you are right...I got the same message. But a small correction. It would retrieve symbol table for trigger only I guess...it didn't work for class...

Comment: Once a symbol table is loaded, Go To will take you to the definition of the variable or function under the cursor.